# On initial load safari browser is giving errors

Tags: safari, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.js app on production server I am getting issue with Safari browser both on desktop and mobile view on initial load. I am using Nuxt version 2.15.8. On initial load Safari browser is giving errors and not applying search on button click and returning these errors on console

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'lValue'. Expected an opening '(' before a function's parameter list
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'y'. Expected an opening '(' before a function's parameter list.
```

Any idea what the issue is?